# Having trouble understanding a seemingly complex function call

Tags: c, function-call

I've been reading through the Riot Vanguard (kernel level anti-cheat driver) source code and have some difficulties understanding what I think is a function call.

```
((void(*)())(RtlFindExportedRoutineByName(VgkDriverObject->DriverStart, "Egg")))();
```

`RtlFindExportedRoutineByName` is a function which returns a `PVOID`, and what I currently have thought up is: take this function which returns a `PVOID`, cast it to a pointer to a function which returns nothing and call it.

Would love some insight from someone who is more knowledgeable.

**EDIT:** Why is this better than just calling the function as it is defined?

Comment: Sounds about right

Comment: What makes you think you might be wrong?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [How to Easily Decipher a Complex Pointer Declarations](https://www.codementor.io/@dankhan/how-to-easily-decipher-complex-pointer-declarations-cpp-so24b66me) Also, here is a nice translator: [C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `RtlFindExportedRoutineByName` is a function which returns a `PVOID`, and what I currently have thought up is: take this function which returns a `PVOID`, cast it to a pointer to a function which returns nothing and call it.

That is correct.

> Why is this better than just calling the function as it is defined?

In order to call a function via a pointer, the pointer must be a function pointer. You cannot call a `PVOID` (which is a `typedef` for `void *`) directly, without casting it beforehand.

The function `RtlFindExportedRoutineByName` is probably returning a pointer to a function that the program does not have direct access to. Therefore, it can only call it via a function pointer.